# Python file won't open from folder. Immediately closes

Tags: python

When I run my script in IDLE it runs perfect, but when I saved this as a .py file and try to open it from the folder, it window blinks for just a second then immediately closes. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
#   average.py
def main():
    print("This program will calculate your final grade for the class.")
    assignment1= eval(input("What is your assignment 1 score?"))
    assignment2= eval(input("What is your assignment 2 score?"))
    assignment3= eval(input("What is your assignment 3 score?"))
    assignment4= eval(input("What is your assignment 4 score?"))
    assignment5= eval(input("What is your assignment 5 score?"))
    assignment6= eval(input("What is your assignment 6 score?"))
    assignment7= eval(input("What is your assignment 7 score?"))
    assignment8= eval(input("What is your assignment 8 score?"))
    assignment9= eval(input("What is your assignment 9 score?"))
    assignment10= eval(input("What is your assignment 10 score?"))
    midterm= eval(input("What is your midterm exam score?"))
    final=eval(input("What is your final exam score?"))
    participation= eval(input("What is your participation score?"))
    average= (((assignment1 + assignment2 + assignment3 + assignment4 + assignment5 + assignment6 + assignment7 + assignment8 + assignment9 + assignment10 + midterm + final + participation)/420)*100)
    print("You final class grade is", average)
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to make your code a little more manageable you should try:
`scores =[] for i in range(1,11): score = eval(input("What is your assignment {} score?".format(i)) scores.append(score)`

Answer (score 2):

Add the boilerplate:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

after your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a command prompt first, then drag your script onto it to run it. Otherwise when the program ends the window closes.

*Edit: and do what @sundance suggested.*

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, are you calling your `main` function?
I mean , did you put a `main()` at the end of your code? If yes, the problem is that python IDLE runs a script and then waits for new code to be executed. This is not the case with python.exe . You have to make the interpreter wait. A common way to do this is adding the line : `raw_input()` at the end of your code which will force the interpreter to wait for (unneeded) user input before it closes and thus printing the result to the screen until someone types something into it and presses return.

Answer (score 0):

@sundance is right. Your code only defines a function, but never calls it, so nothing happens when you run the script. You need to call the function for its body to be executed, hence the `main()` call is needed.

On a side note, your code can be optimized as follows:

```
tasks = ['assignment {}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 11)] + [
    'midterm exam', 'final exam', 'participation']
sum_scores = sum(
    float(input('What is your {} score? '.format(task)))
        for task in tasks)
average = sum_scores / 420 * 100
print('Your final class grade is', average)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `average.py`, you are only defining functions. So, when you execute the script there are only function definitions and no function calls. You'll need to call your `main()` function at the end of the script. Just add `main()` at the end of your code